# How get zabbix enabled host,Through the use of API

Tags: python, zabbix

This is my code,it can get all host.I just need enabled host.

```
import requests
import csv
import json

url = 'https://xxxx.zabbix.com/api_jsonrpc.php'
post_data = {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "host.get",
    "params": {
        "filter":{
            "with_monitored_items": True},
        "output":
            ["host"],
        "selectInterfaces":
            ["ip"]},
    "id": 1,
    "auth": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}

post_header = {'Content-Type': 'application/json-rpc'}


ret = requests.post(url,
                    data=json.dumps(post_data),
                    headers=post_header,
                    verify=False)
data = ret.json()['result']
# print(data)
parsed_result = [{'host': i['host'], 'eth0': i['interfaces'][0]['ip'],
                  'type': 'vm', 'status': 'online'} for i in data]
print(parsed_result)
with open("data.csv", "w") as file:
    csv_file = csv.writer(file)
    header = ['hostname', 'eth0', 'type', 'status']
    data_rows = [(i['host'], i['eth0'], i['type'], i['status']) for i in parsed_result]  # NOQA
    csv_file.writerow(header)
    csv_file.writerows(data_rows)
```

What should I do？This is zabbix doc:
https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/api/reference/host/get

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your [host](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/api/reference/host/object) filter, add filtering for `status` of 0, possibly like so:

```
"filter":{
        "with_monitored_items": True,
        "status": "0"},
```